# Building app with cordova met with unknown error:Command failed with UNKNOWN

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I'm working on a project and trying to generate the android version of it through Cordova.But every time i type in cordova build android i encounter the same problem:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Loaded API for android project D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js
Checking for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
[Gradle Properties] Preparing Configuration
[Gradle Properties] Appending default configuration properties
[Gradle Properties] Appending custom configuration properties 
[Gradle Properties] Updating and Saving File
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms\android\platform_www] to platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www
  copy  platforms\android\platform_www\cordova.js platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\cordova.js (updated file)
  copy  www\css\index.css platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\css\index.css (updated file)
  copy  www\index.html platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\index.html (updated file)
  copy  www\js\index.js platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www\js\index.js (updated file)
Wrote out android application name "HelloCordova" to D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "io.cordova.hellocordova" to D:/Documents/JavaScript/cordova_test/test3/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/io/cordova/hellocordova/MainActivity.java
This app does not have launcher icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
Updating splash screens at platforms\android\app\src\main\res
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\Android_SDK (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android_SDK (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: D:\Android_SDK
Command failed with UNKNOWN: D:\gradle-7.6-all\gradle-7.6\bin\gradle.BAT -p D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android wrapper -b D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
spawn UNKNOWN
Error: Command failed with UNKNOWN: D:\gradle-7.6-all\gradle-7.6\bin\gradle.BAT -p D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android wrapper -b D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:713:9)
    at execa (D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\node_modules\execa\index.js:83:26)
    at ProjectBuilder.runGradleWrapper (D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\builders\ProjectBuilder.js:125:20)
    at D:\Documents\JavaScript\cordova_test\test3\node_modules\cordova-android\lib\builders\ProjectBuilder.js:272:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I've checked my environment variables many times and found no problem with it.Also i typein cordova requirements to check and i found everything i need have been installed:
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-33,android-32,android-30
Gradle: installed D:\gradle-7.6-all\gradle-7.6\bin\gradle.BAT

I'm frustrated now because i don't know how to solve this and i searched google finding no one has  the same error.Plz guide me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building for cordova-android 10.0.0 or higher, you need to use JAVA 11 or higher. jdk 1.8 will cause errors. Also, Node needs to be 12+, not sure which version of that you are using, but those errors are also pretty non-descriptive.
Here are the update docs for cordova 10.0.0: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html.